# Statement of "proof by contradiction"

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Wikipedia states:

> In mathematical logic, the proof by contradiction is represented as
>   "if $S \cup \{ P \} \vdash \mathbb{F}$ then $S  \vdash \neg P$"
>   or
>   "if $S \cup \{ \neg P \} \vdash \mathbb{F}$ then $S  \vdash P$".

Is it true? Are the two really the same? I think it is impossible for one to deduce the "law of excluded middle" from the the second representation, but possible to do so using the first. Am I wrong?

Law of excluded middle states that "Everything is either true or false". I know how to use the first statement of RAA (proof by contradiction) to prove this law, but is it possible to do so using the second statement?

Why I claim it to be impossible, you ask? Because in the natural system of deduction, RAA is the only way to introduce a $\neg$ to the right-hand side. Replacing the first form, with the second, I see no way of introducing $\neg$ to right-hand side.

Comment: The second version is non-constructive, yes. I mean this point is adressed at the bottom of the Wikipedia subsection you quoted from, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction#In_mathematical_logic).

Comment: The two are equivalent from the point of view of *classical* logic, where the Law of Double Negation : $\lnot \lnot P \vdash P$ holds. In [intuitionistic logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) where it does not hold, the two rules are nor more equivalent.

Comment: So, you guys would agree that using the second one instead of the first makes the system incomplete, unless law of double negation is taken as a rule. Right?

Comment: What you can say for the second statement works just like the first $S \cup \{ (\neg P) \} \vdash \mathbb{F}$ then $S\vdash \lnot (\lnot P)$. Then, if you accept double negation, $\lnot \lnot P \equiv P$. If not, we conclude simply $\lnot (\lnot P)$.

Comment: Yes, incomplete according to the "standard" classical semantics (truth-tables)... *Double Negation* and *Law of Excluded Middle* are equivalent, and thus both are rejected in intuitionistic logic.

Comment: @amWhy: You can't claim that $S \vdash \neg \neg P$ means $S \vdash P$, unless you take double negation as a rule.

Comment: @Untitled That is exactly what I said: "**if you accept** double negation, then... $P\equiv \lnot \lnot P$". "If not...we conclude simply $\lnot(\lnot P)$." (the latter conclusion following as per the first statement). Please read my comments more carefully.

Comment: @Untitled: Are you sure you can conclude the law of excluded middle from the _first_ of the principles you present? Actually it is the other way around.

Comment: This blog post by Andrej Bauer, [Proof of negation and proof by contradiction](http://math.andrej.com/2010/03/29/proof-of-negation-and-proof-by-contradiction/), discusses this topic.

Answer (score 3):

The two formulations are easily equivalent if $\vdash \neg\neg P\leftrightarrow P$, as is the case in classical logic but not in intuitionistic logic.

In intuitionistic logic they are not the same. Indeed, the inference
$$ \tag{1} \frac{S,P\vdash \bot}{S\vdash \neg P}$$
is intuitionistically valid (and is the canonical way of establishing $\neg P$ intuitionistically), whereas
$$ \tag{2} \frac{S,\neg P\vdash \bot}{S\vdash P} $$
is *not* intuitionistically valid. Adding the latter rule to intuitionistic logic will produce classical logic.

The law of excluded middle is, of course, another example of something that is classically but not intuitionistically valid. Therefore it cannot be proved using only (1)  (and other intuitionistically valid rules).

The law of excluded middle *can* be proved using (2) -- namely, $\neg(A\lor \neg A)\vdash \bot$ is intuitionistically valid, and one application of (2) will then conclude $A\lor \neg A$.

To reach a contradiction from $\neg(A\lor \neg A)$, use the fact that $\neg(P\lor Q)\vdash \neg P$ intuitionistically to conclude first $\neg A$ and then $\neg\neg A$, which contradict each other.

Answer (score 0):

The "common" approach to [intuitionistic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) and *classical* logic with *Natural Deduction* is to assume $\bot$ (the *falsum*) as primitive and define $\lnot A$ as an abbreviation for $A \to \bot$.

In this way, from the rules for $\to$ :

> > $$\frac {A \, \, A \to B} B \, \, (\to E)$$
> >
> > $$\frac {A \vdash B} {A \to B} \, \, (\to I)$$

we can derive the rules for $\lnot$ :

> > $$\frac {A \, \, \lnot A } \bot \, \, (\lnot E)$$
> >
> > $$\frac {A \vdash \bot} {\lnot A} \, \, (\lnot I)$$

Up to now, the rules are both classicaly and intuitionistically valid.

In addition, classical logic adds one more rule :

> > $$\frac {\lnot A \vdash \bot } A$$

called *Double negation*, or *Rule of indirect proof* or *Reductio ad absurdum*.

With it, we can prove *Excluded Middle* :

> > $$\frac { } {\lnot A \lor A}$$

---

Proof of : $A \lor \lnot A$.

1) $A$ --- assumed [a]

2) $A \lor \lnot A$ --- from 1) by $\lor$-I

3) $\lnot (A \lor \lnot A)$ --- assumed [b]

4) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 3) by $\lnot$-E

5) $\lnot A$ --- from 1) and 4) by $\lnot$-I, discharging assumption [a]

6) $A \lor \lnot A$ --- from 5) by $\lor$-I

7) $\bot$ --- from 3) and 6) by $\lnot$-E

> 8) $A \lor \lnot A$ --- from 3) and 7) by *DN*, discharging [b] : this is the crucial step that is intuitionistically **not** valid.